# Сгруппировать вывод в gridview

Tags: yii2

В гриде одной из колонок присвоено такое value

```
'value' => function ($data) {

                $m = 'г';
                $g = 'с';
                $ps = 'пс';

                $summ = 0;
                $str = '';
                $strt = '';

                foreach($data->itemsOrder as $request) {
                    $summ = $request->order_items_quantity;
                    $str .=  (strlen($str))?', ': '';

                    $externalId = $request->orderInfo->order_items_offer_externalId;
                    if($externalId == 'cream-009-1' or $externalId == 'cream-009-2'){
                        $strt = $m;
                    }
                    elseif($externalId == 'cream-002-1' or $externalId == 'cream-002-2'){
                        $strt = $g;
                    }

                    elseif($externalId == 'cream-005-1' or $externalId == 'cream-005-2'){
                        $strt = $ps;

                    }
                    else{
                        $strt = '';
                    }
                    if(strstr($strt, $ps)){
                        $str .= $summ.$strt;
                    }
                    elseif(strstr($strt, $g)){
                        $str .=  $summ.$strt;
                    }
                    elseif(strstr($strt, $m)){
                        $str .=  $summ.$strt;
                    }
                    else{
                        $str .=  '';
                    }
                }

                return $str;
            },
        ],
```

Вывод получается вида `6пс, 2пс, 6г, 2г, 1с`, Как можно привести к виду: `8пс, 8г, 1с`?

Upd. нашел рещение

Comment: Можно вопрос. Как все это относится к yii2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if(strstr($strt, $ps)){
                        $str += $summ;
                    }
                    elseif(strstr($strt, $g)){
                        $str +=  $summ;
                    }
                    elseif(strstr($strt, $m)){
                        $str +=  $summ;
                    }
                    else{
                        $str .=  '';
                    }
                }
 return $str.$strt;
```